# Save Carriage Return in CSV

Tags: php, newline, blogs

I have to create a Blog-Site with PHP.

At the moment, I save the text of each new blogentry in a .txt file with the title, actual date and an ID.

this works well as long as - and this is the problem - I don't enter a Carriage return. Everytime I press the "Enter" key, the entry won't show up properly because it identifies the new line as a new entry.

How would you solve this? thank you for your answers

Here is the PHP Code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["newpost"])){

    $datum = date('d.m.Y H:i:s');

    $file2 = file('./data/blog/'.$userid.'.txt');
    $titel = $_POST['titel'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    foreach ($file2 as $filee) 
            {
                $blog_details = explode(';', $filee);
                $id_stored = $blog_details[0];
            }
                if (!empty($id_stored))
                    {
                        $id = $id_stored +1;
                    } else
                    {
                        $id = 1;
                    }
                        $file = fopen('./data/blog/'.$userid.'.txt', 'a+');
                        $text = $id . ";" . $datum . ";" . $titel . ";" . $body . PHP_EOL;
                        if(fwrite($file, $text)) 
                        {           
                        echo "Dein Blogeintrag wurde gespeichert.";
                        fclose ($file);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "fail!";
                        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Consider using database for storing blog posts. If you really want to use files, I would store each post in separate file or create some "custom" format and use, say, 3 newlines for delimiting posts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I have to store this in a text or csv file and can't use a sql db. I will try your tip, using 3 newlines instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You could tokenise any EOL characters in $body before concatenating it into $text, using a suitably unlikely token, eg `#EOL#`...
`str_replace("\n",'#EOL#',$body)`
...that way any blog entries should only occupy one line in your text file.
Of course you would need to do the opposite when recovering the blog entry, replacing the token with an actual EOL etc.
NB, you may need to be a little more flexible in identifying the original EOLs in cases where the blog entry may contain '\r\n' etc, but you get the idea.